# accessing protected object in array

Tags: php, drupal

what would be the correct syntax to access body, as these are objects not arrays and the parent objects is node:protected

```
 CourseObjectContent Object
    (
        [node:protected] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 9397
                [type] => book
                [language] => 
                [uid] => 1
                [status] => 1
                [created] => 1364217732
                [changed] => 1367581312
                [comment] => 0
                [promote] => 0
                [moderate] => 0
                [sticky] => 0
                [tnid] => 0
                [translate] => 0
                [vid] => 9406
                [revision_uid] => 1
                [title] => title text
                [body] => "body text"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protected (and same with Private) members/properties/variables of class are not directly accessible out of class or not accessible directly by class Object. So you need to write a Class Member Function for this to access Protected Object Array of that class

```
class CourseObjectContent {
    protected $node;

    //member function to access 'protected' members of class
    function accessObjectArray(){
        //TODO:Your code to access protected object array
    }
    //other member functions
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must write a function inside the class of your object to return 'body' value. Only functions belongs to the same class can access protected values of that class.

Comment: inherited or parent classes can access protected vars/methods. Private vars/methods are only accessible from the class.